# how to link to latest version of a class/method on javadoc.io

Tags: javadoc, github-pages

I want to link my github-java-project-wiki pages to methods of the javadoc of the lib via http://javadoc.io

The project wiki is about geo uri dataformats which should be linked to class-methods uesd to process the format.

Example there should be a link between

- Dataformat geo latitude https://github.com/k3b/k3b-geoHelper/wiki/data#ll
- javaproperty for latitude http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.k3b/k3b-geoHelper/1.1.4/de/k3b/geo/api/IGeoPointInfo.html#getLatitude()

My **problem**: the link to class/method contains a version-number **"1.1.4"**

My **question**: Is it possible to have a link to the **latest version** instead of a concrete version?

On artifact level i can link to

- http://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.k3b/k3b-geoHelper/

which will redirect to the latest version

- http://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.k3b/k3b-geoHelper/1.1.4

But i donot know how to do this on class level

Alternativly is there something like a placeholder-variable in github-wiki so i can write

```
http://static.javadoc.io/com.github.k3b/k3b-geoHelper/${VERSIONNUMBER}/de/k3b/geo/api/IGeoPointInfo.html#getLatitude()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted the owners of javadoc.io and they just deployed the new feature. You link like this: http://javadoc.io/page/org.mockito/mockito-all/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html

I use this feature in Mockito framework to avoid hosting docs in gh-pages and simplify greatly [Mockito's automated release process](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Continuous-Delivery-Overview).

javadoc.io is fantastic!

Comment: You may want to use `mockito-core` instead of `mockito-all` ;)